# Let $x, y, z \in [0, 2 \pi]$. Prove that $|x-z| + |y-z| + |x-y| \leq 4 \pi$.

Tags: inequality

I've managed to prove this inequality. But the proof I have found is long and it is basically using again and again the elementary fact that for any $ a>0, v \in \mathbb{R}$, $|v| \leq a \Leftrightarrow -a \leq v \leq a$. I was wondering if anyone can find a simpler algebraic proof.

Comment: The trick is to assume that this numbers can be arranged ans $min \le mid \le max$ and we have, one way or another $|\pm(max - min)| + |\pm (max - mid)| + |\pm(mid - min)|$.  Then you just have do *one* proof *once*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have a representation of any number subtract another number.

So if we relabel them as $a = \min(x,y,z)$ and $c = \max(x,y,z)$ and $b = $ the middle value.

Then *one* of $|x-z|$ or $|x-y|$ or $|y-z|$ is going to be either $|a-c|$ or $|c-a|$ (which are equal).  And *another* on of them will be either $|b-c|$ or $|c-b|$.  And the third will be either $|a-b|$ or $|b-c|$.  We don't know which one is labeled nor if it's one term subtract the other of in the order, but it doesn't matter as 1) Order of subtraction doesn't matter when you take the absolute value.  and 2) it doesn't matter *which* of $x,y,z$ is largest, smallest or middle, as we *do* know every combination will be done (in way or another.

So $|x-z| +|y-z| + |x-y| = |\pm(x-z)| + |\pm(y-z)| + |\pm(x-y)|$

$=|c-a|+|c-b|+|b-a|$.

And as we are assuming $a \le b \le c$ then this is equal to $(c-a) + (b-a) + (c-b)= 2c- 2a$.

Now the *very* most $c$ can be is (just under) $2\pi$.  And the very least $a$ can be is $0$.  So the most $2c -2a$ can be is $4\pi$.

Or in other words.  $0 \le a \le c$ and $c < 2\pi$ so $2c -2a \le 2c < 2(2\pi) = 4\pi$.

Comment: +1 : elegantly composed attack on the complication.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, suppose $x \leq y \leq z$. Then we wish to show that $(z - x) + (z - y) + (y - x) \leq 4 \pi$. We see that $(z - x) + (z - y) + (y - x) = 2z - 2x \leq 2z \leq 2 (2\pi) = 4\pi$.

Comment: "Without loss of generality, suppose x≤y≤z."  I think at the OP's level *why* we can assume that is probably not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the expression is permutation invariant. This means that if we switch the places of the three variables the expression does not change. This means that we can assume without loss of generality that $x\geq y \geq z$. Then the expression simplifies to $2(x-z)$ which is obviously less than or equal to $4\pi$ (chose $x=2\pi$ and $z=0$).

Comment: It's not just that it's cyclic, you're using that it's invariant under all permutations of $x,y,z$.  Otherwise you can only assume either $x \ge y \ge z$ or $x \ge z \ge y$.